# How do I add a redirect to thank you page after form submission in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add a redirect to a 'thank you' page (thankyou.html) after form submission in this .js code. Currently it apends a message.

```js
$.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Enable button & show success message
                    $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Thank You! Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');
```

Comment: Use ``window.location = "thankyou.html";`` to redirect to new page

Comment: Where would I need to put that code?

Comment: Inside your ``success: function() { //the above mentioned code goes here }``

Comment: I'll give that a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by adding `window.location = "thankyou.html";` like this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Enable button & show success message
                    $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Thank You! Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');
                    // Add it here
                    window.location = "thankyou.html";
```